# Does a tool for testing web applications with different bandwidths exist?

Tags: web-application

I am currently starting to develop a web-application. This application should also upload a significant amount of data.

**Does a tool exist, with which I can limit the upload and download speed for some applications or the whole computer?**

(Ubuntu Linux or Windows 7, preferably both)

Answer (score 5):

[Shunra](http://www.shunra.com/) has tools to simulate a variety of network impairments- bandwidth, latency or packet loss (and maybe more).

Answer (score 3):

On linux environments you can use the [netem](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem) application which allows you to emulate a very wide range of networking circumstances.

You are able to control latency, packet loss, jitter, and limit bandwidth without needing to create new devices or configure applications any differently.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `network throttling` setting in `chrome` devtools. It has a couple of preconfigured profiles (3g, 4g, etc.) and a possibility to set custom **download, upload and latency** settings. Accessible through `network` tab, here:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please check Aptimize Latency Simulator Tool. This can be used to simulate network latency (locally hosted, remotely hosted). The bandwidth would differ in both cases.

1. Download tool from [link](http://www.aptimize.com/downloads/file/latency-simulator.zip)
2. Walkthrough video - [link](http://www.aptimize.com/blog/latency-simulator), This link seems removed adding [link](http://sqlandsiva.blogspot.in/2011/09/qa-free-tool-aptimize-latency-simulator.html) from my notes

Answer (score 0):

If a single user, check out Charles Proxy.  While Shunra's offerings (now a part of HP) are the presidential armored Cadillac of solutions, and well worth the money, sometimes they are overkill.   Charles can slow down the connection to allow you to look at the performance as it degrades over connection speed just fine.

http://www.charlesproxy.com/

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you can use the trickle command to limit a process's network speed.  Here is the short description from the trickle website:

> trickle is a portable lightweight userspace bandwidth shaper. It can run in collaborative mode (together with trickled) or in stand alone mode.
>
> trickle works by taking advantage of the unix loader preloading. Essentially it provides, to the application, a new version of the functionality that is required to send and receive data through sockets. It then limits traffic based on delaying the sending and receiving of data over a socket. trickle runs entirely in userspace and does not require root privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Both LoadRunner and NeoLoad have got functionality to simulate different bandwidths. Both tools have a free license to use with up to 50 virtual users. Only LoadRunner has the possibilitey to measure client side renedring in the tools itself using TruClient.

- LoadRunner (Micro Focus): [Post about Network Emulation](https://community.microfocus.com/t5/Application-Delivery-Management/Network-Emulation-Truly-evaluating-the-impact-of-network/ba-p/1631832)
- NeoLoad (Neotys): [Using WAN Emulation](https://www.neotys.com/blog/using-wan-emulation-requirements/)